# Get the list of all followers ids from twitter using tweepy in python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to retrieve the list of followers id for more than 1 million followers. I am able to retrieve the record by limiting the request.but since to retrieve whole followers ids it will take around more than 15 hours. but for this long time i can't keep on pushing the request. So i am looking for an alternative like that i can somehow store cursorID so that after some time i can make a call from that cursor point instead of again starting from intial step.

My python code is like this

```
  import time
  import tweepy
  consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret = "consumerkey", 
                                                                  "" ,  "", ""
  auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
  auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
  api = tweepy.API(auth)
  ids = []
  current_cursor = ""
  for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name="shahidkapoor").pages():
#current_cursor = cursor.iterator.next_cursor
    cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, screen_name="shahidkapoor",  
    cursor =  current_cursor)
current_cursor = cursor.iterator.next_cursor
print repr(cursor)
print current_cursor
ids.extend(page)
#print page
time.sleep(20)

  print len(ids)
```

I want some way to keep track of cursor or some variable so i can make a request from that position onwards instead of starting from fresh.

Answer (score 1):

For each Tweepy search, tell Twitter to only give you items you haven't seen before.

1. set `since_id=None`
2. do Tweepy search, passing in `since_id`
3. calculate max ID of the results from each row of #2
4. go to #2

See: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/21516

Comment: But I think getting followers id can be done through cursor and the above method is basically for getting the tweets where since_ID plays a major role

Comment: anand: oops, you're correct, I'd copied the pseudocode from my own stuff -- using an explicit cursor is better.